# Mastermind Game in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have already looked at this thread [Python Mastermind Game Troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648407/python-mastermind-game-troubles) on your website but the question I am asking is slightly different as I have been given a different task.

This is the question:

**Generate a random four digit number. The player has to keep inputting four digit numbers until they guess the randomly generated number. After each unsuccessful try it should say how many numbers they got correct, but not which position they got right. At the end of the game should congratulate the user and say how many tries it took.**

I have made this so far:

```
from random import randint

n1 = randint (1,9)
n2 = randint (1,9)
n3 = randint (1,9)
n4 = randint (1,9)
numberswrong = 0
print (n1,n2,n3,n4)
guess1 = input("guess the first number")
guess2 = input("guess the second number")
guess3 = input("guess the third number")
guess4 = input("guess the fourth number")
guess1 = int (guess1)
guess2 = int (guess2)
guess3 = int (guess3)
guess4 = int (guess4)
if guess1 != n1:
    numberswrong +=1
else:
    numberswrong +=0   
if guess2 != n2:
    numberswrong +=1
else:
    numberswrong +=0 
if guess3 != n3:
    numberswrong +=1
else:
    numberswrong +=0 
if guess4 != n4:
    numberswrong +=1
else:
    numberswrong +=0 
print ("you got",numberswrong, "numbers wrong")
if numberswrong == 0:
    print ("Well done")
while numberswrong != 0:
    guess1 = input("guess the first number")
    guess2 = input("guess the second number")
    guess3 = input("guess the third number")
    guess4 = input("guess the fourth number")
    guess1 = int (guess1)
    guess2 = int (guess2)
    guess3 = int (guess3)
    guess4 = int (guess4)
    if guess1 != n1:
        numberswrong +=1
    else:
        numberswrong +=0   
    if guess2 != n2:
        numberswrong +=1
    else:
        numberswrong +=0 
    if guess3 != n3:
        numberswrong +=1
    else:
        numberswrong +=0 
    if guess4 != n4:
        numberswrong +=1
    else:
        numberswrong +=0 
    print ("you got",numberswrong, "numbers wrong")
print ("Well done")
```

The print (n1,n2,n3,n4) is just to test the code and won't be there in the real code. I am having two problems. Firstly, if you guess the number first time, two "Well done"'s are shown and second how do I clear the numberswrong variable without ruining the while loop.If I don't do anything the numberswrong variable goes up everytime you get an incorrect guess well past four so even when you guess right, you don't get the well done message as numberswrong equals like 25 or something similar. Also, if you just say numberswrong=0 at the end of the while loop the while loop thinks you got it correct and says well done. I don't know what the solution is. A loop counter maybe?

Help would be appreciated

Edit: I see why the "Well Done" is printed twice. As for the second query. Still can't see it.

Edit No.2: @moose. I will answer this as best as I can. When I press run the program says the number asks me what numbers 1-4 are and then tells me the number of numbers I have got wrong. Only problem is the number of numbers goes up and isn't cleared. Lets say I got all the numbers wrong 3 times. On the third time it says you got 12 numbers wrong. Obviously I can't get 12 numbers wrong because there is only 4 numbers to guess. I see what is happening the while loop is not clearing after each pass. I think I know the solution. Say somewhere numberswrong=0 to clear the loop. But I don't know where to put this statement.

Comment: Can you please explain your case with good examples?

Comment: I mean explain the input/output of your program with examples

Comment: Look through your code line by line asking yourself what is printing "Well done" and when.  As for the second ask yourself when does `numberswrong` get checked and what is `numberswrong` tracking.  Then you will see your error.

Comment: I don't want to seem rude but can't you just run it?

Comment: @Derek A good question should not require any additional effort for skilled people to answer. The question has to contain everything: What you did, what you expected to happen, what happened instead (typically, for this type of question).

Comment: @Derek Thanks for adding the extra information to your question. To add to what moose said, people reading your question shouldn't need to run your code just so they can understand the question properly. That not only applies to the people answering, it's also for the benefit of people with a similar problem who find your question in the future. If you do your best to write great questions that will inspire people to respond with awesome answers, then together we can create pages that not only help you with your immediate problems, they may also help many others in the years to come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated code! I’ve used a variable c to keep track of the number of tries. I also break out of the infinite loop when the user has correctly guessed the number.

```
from random import randint

n1 = randint(1,9)
n2 = randint(1,9)
n3 = randint(1,9)
n4 = randint(1,9)
c = 1

while True:
    print (n1,n2,n3,n4)
    guess1 = input("guess the first number")
    guess2 = input("guess the second number")
    guess3 = input("guess the third number")
    guess4 = input("guess the fourth number")
    guess1 = int(guess1)
    guess2 = int(guess2)
    guess3 = int(guess3)
    guess4 = int(guess4)
    numberswrong = 0

    if guess1 != n1:
        numberswrong += 1
    if guess2 != n2:
        numberswrong += 1

    if guess3 != n3:
        numberswrong += 1

    if guess4 != n4:
        numberswrong += 1

    if numberswrong == 0:
        print('Well Done!')
        print('It took you ' + str(c) + ' ries to guess the number!')
        break
    else:
        print('You got ' + str(4-numberswrong) + ' numbers right.')
    c += 1
```

Comment: Sorry but I keep getting this error.                                                        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ding/Documents/Ding/School Work/ICT/GCSE/Codes/Summer Holiday Work/Programs/Mastermind Program Possibly Fixed.py", line 35, in <module>
    print ("You got") + str(4-numberswrong) + ("numbers right.")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: @Derek are you running Python3? Because my code not not have brackets  `print ("You got") + str(4-numberswrong) + ("numbers right.") `

Comment: I am running Python 3.4

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to reset your numberswrong variable to zero :)

As a side note, to spot bugs, try to make your code simpler.

- Count the number of right numbers, instead of the number of wrong ones!
- Use lists instead of copy pasting code.
- Once you feel more confortable with loops, use python generators
- Use text formatting instead of string concatenation.
- Name your variables with names that make sense (avoid "c" when you can call it "num_tries")
- Comment!

It you try to apply all this advices, you final code should look like this:

```
from random import randint

# Init variable
numbers = [randint(1, 9) for _ in range(4)]
num_tries = 0
guesses = None

# Loop while numbers and guesses are not the same.
while numbers != guesses:
    # Ask user to guess the 4 values
    guesses = [
        int(input("guess the first number: ")),
        int(input("guess the second number: ")),
        int(input("guess the third number: ")),
        int(input("guess the fourth number: "))
    ]

    num_tries += 1

    # Display message with number of right numbers.
    num_right_numbers = len([1 for i in range(4) if numbers[i] == guesses[i]])
    print 'You got {0} numbers right.'.format(num_right_numbers)

# User won, print message and quit.
print 'Well Done!'
print 'It took you {0} tries to guess the number!'.format(num_tries)
```

Comment: That's nice & compact. However, the OP is using Python 3, so they have to use the `print()` function, not the `print` statement. You can get the [print() function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) in Python 2.6+ by putting `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of the program before any other `import` statements.