# Implementing Cows and Bulls game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to code the [Cows and Bulls game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulls_and_Cows) in which I have to generate 4 random number and ask the users to guess it. I have been trying for the past few hours to code it but can't seem to come up with a solution.

The output I want is:

```
Welcome to cows and Bulls game.
Enter a number:     
>> 1234
2 Cows, 0 Bulls.
>> 1286 
1 Cows, 1 Bulls. 
>> 1038    
Congrats, you got it in 3 tries.
```

So far, I have got this:

```
print("Welcome to Cows and Bulls game.")

import random 


def number(x, y):
  cowsNbulls = [0, 0]
  for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[1] == y[i]:
      cowsNbulls[1] += 1
    else:
      cowsNbulls[0] += 1
  return cowsNbulls;


x = str(random.randint(0, 9999))
guess = 0 

while True:
    y = input("Enter a number: ")
    count = number(x, y)
    guess += 1

    print(str(count[0]), "Cows.", str(count[1]), "Bulls")
    if count[1] == 4:
      False 
      print("Congrats, you done it in", str(guess))
    else:
      break;
```

And the output is:

```
Welcome to Cows and Bull game.

Enter a number: 1234 
4 Cows, 0 Bulls.
```

It would not continue. I was just wondering what the problem is.

Comment: FWIW, I don't know what a cows and bulls game is…

Comment: Try removing the `else: break;` lines.

Comment: It will have to randomly generate a 4-digit number and ask the user to guess it. For every digit that the user guessed correctly in the correct place, they have a “cow”. For every digit the user guessed correctly in the wrong place is a “bull.” @deceze

Comment: So with four numbers in the wrong place you win? (Dues to your code.)

Comment: @Ollie I just removed the 'else: break'. It works for the first round and would not continue for the next.

Comment: @KlausD. it seems to be that way..

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648407/python-mastermind-game-troubles

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print(str(count[0]), "Cows.", str(count[1]), "Bulls")
  if count[0] == 4:
    print("Congrats, you done it in", str(guess))
    break
```

You want to break the `while` loop if the count equals 4, otherwise it should continue to run.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things wrong with your code:

- The **while True** statement has the same indent level as a function
- Inside the while statement you use **break** which is why the statement only executes once if you fail to get the correct anwser the first time
- "x & y" variables?? Please in the future use vars that make sense, not only to you, but to others
- In the function "**number**" you have a this validation `x[1] == y[i]` this wont do anything, it will only compare the first char of the string

Below I made some repairs to your code, see if it's something like this that you are looking for:

```
import random

def number(rand_num, guess):
  cowsNbulls = {
    'cow': 0,
    'bull': 0,
  }

  for i in range(len(rand_num)):
    try:
      if rand_num[i] == guess[i]:
        cowsNbulls['cow'] += 1
      else:
        cowsNbulls['bull'] += 1
    except:
      pass

  return cowsNbulls;

def game_start():
  rand_number = str(random.randint(1, 9999))
  tries = 0 
  locked = True

  print("Welcome to Cows and Bulls game.")

  while locked:
    print(rand_number)
    guess = input("Enter a number (Limit = 9999): ")
    cows_n_bulls = number(rand_number, guess)
    tries += 1

    print(str(cows_n_bulls['cow']), "Cows.", str(cows_n_bulls['bull']), "Bulls")
    if cows_n_bulls['cow'] == 4:
      print("Congrats, you done it in", str(tries))
      locked = False


game_start()
```